# Why is 1 for-loop slower than 2 for-loops in problem related to prefix sum matrix?

Tags: c++, performance, for-loop, prefix-sum

I'm recently doing [this problem](https://lqdoj.edu.vn/problem/pvhoi20b1qol), taken directly and translated from day 1 task 3 of IOI 2010, ["Quality of life"](https://www.ioi2010.org/Tasks/Day1/Quality_of_Living.shtml), and I encountered a weird phenomenon.

I was setting up a 0-1 matrix and using that to calculate a prefix sum matrix in 1 loop:

```
for (int i = 1; i <= m; i++)
{
    for (int j = 1; j <= n; j++)
    {
        if (a[i][j] < x) {lower[i][j] = 0;} else {lower[i][j] = 1;}
        b[i][j] = b[i-1][j] + b[i][j-1] - b[i-1][j-1] + lower[i][j];
    }
}
```

and I got TLE (time limit exceeded) on 4 tests (the time limit is 2.0s). While using 2 for loop seperately:

```
for (int i = 1; i <= m; i++)
{
    for (int j = 1; j <= n; j++)
    {
        if (a[i][j] < x) {lower[i][j] = 0;} else {lower[i][j] = 1;}
    }
}

for (int i = 1; i <= m; i++)
{
    for (int j = 1; j <= n; j++)
    {
        b[i][j] = b[i-1][j] + b[i][j-1] - b[i-1][j-1] + lower[i][j];
    }
}
```

got me full AC (accepted).

As we can see from the 4 pictures here:

- TLE result, picture 1 : https://i.stack.imgur.com/9o5C2.png
- TLE result, picture 2 : https://i.stack.imgur.com/TJwX5.png
- AC result, picture 1 : https://i.stack.imgur.com/1fo2H.png
- AC result, picture 2 : https://i.stack.imgur.com/CSsZ2.png

the 2 for-loops code generally ran a bit faster (even in accepted test cases), contrasting my logic that the single for-loop should be quicker. Why does this happened?

Full code (AC) : https://pastebin.com/c7at11Ha (Please ignore all the nonsense bit and stuff like `using namespace std;`, as this is a competitive programming contest).

- Note : The judge server, [lqdoj.edu.vn](https://lqdoj.edu.vn/) is built on [dmoj.ca](https://dmoj.ca/), a global competitive programming contest platform.

Comment: Do you really need to store `lower` for later use? Why not just add on `int(a[i][j] >= x)`?

Comment: @Brannon Not really, to be honest... oops.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at [assembly](https://godbolt.org/z/8jcWWY7en) you'll see the source of the difference:

1. Single loop:

```
{
    if (a[i][j] < x)
    {
        lower[i][j] = 0;
    }
    else
    {
        lower[i][j] = 1;
    }
    b[i][j] = b[i-1][j] 
            + b[i][j-1]
            - b[i-1][j-1]
            + lower[i][j];
}
```

In this case, there's a data dependency. The assignment to `b` depends on the value from the assignment to `lower`. So the operations go sequentially in the loop - first assignment to `lower`, then to `b`. The compiler can't optimize this code significantly because of the dependency.

2. Separation of assignments into 2 loops:

The assignment to `lower` is now independent and the compiler can use [SIMD instructions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SIMD) that leads to a performance boost in the first loop. The second loop stays more or less similar to the original assembly.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I'm not really familiar with Assembly, so could you elaborate further what are "simd instructions" in this case and how they affect the running time here? I assume that it's the part from line 163-212 that make the difference, but I'm not really sure what it does.

Comment: @silverfox Single Instruction Multiple Data. one instruction processes several input items packed into a special long register, e.g. sum several integers at once. in your case, for example, pcmpgtd instruction compares several array elements at once and movdqu saves all the results (0/1) into the destination. (instructions are for x86, arm has its own simd instructions)